# Importing and calling a list of different commands as functions

Tags: python, python-3.x, serial-port, pyserial

Currently I am trying to understand how a controlling software communicates with a modem/DCE through a serial port. I am using PySerial in Python for this purpose. I managed to passively listen to the communication of the two and do have a list of byte-strings (e.g. `b'\x1d\x10\xff'`) the software sends while performing several single actions.

To fully understand the command-structure and the responses I want use a **trial-and-error approach** and mimic the controlling software with my own PC by extending my 'listen only'-script by sending commands and listen afterwards for the response. Right now I defined these commands as functions, for example:

```
def Testcommand1():
    if serial.isOpen() == True:
        serial.write(b'\x1d\x10\xff')
        print('Testcommand1 to do some specific stuff sent, awaiting response.')
    else:
        print('ERROR: Serial port is closed')
```

In the end I will have 20-30 different commands. I plan to define them in a different file and call them from there. As I understand in order to call them I need to import each function individually, like

```
from commandfile import Testcommand1()
from commandfile import Testcommand2()
from commandfile import Testcommand3()
...
```

That's the point where I'm starting to doubt my approach (because I would have 20-30 lines before I start my actual 'listen'-program): is this really the best way? Or is there something slender and smarter as `def function()` to define my commands I want to send?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`from commandfile import Testcommand1()` won't work.

`from commandfile import Testcommand1` will.

You could also import them all doing

```
from commandfile import *
```

Comment: Ah! I see! Looks better, thanks. Is there, by the way, some (similar) way to print a list of every function available? Basically to see a list of all the functions before deciding which one to call via `input()` or something

Comment: @Tobitobitobi: You're asking a different question. The basic answer is yes, you can determine what attributes a module, like `commandfile` contains (and which are likely function because they're callable). Folks often use some sort of naming convention to help find the ones they want.